# Jetbrains Hub Microsoft auth module configuration for Office organisation (sharepoint)

Tags: youtrack, jetbrains-hub

I'm having issues setting up the Microsoft auth module for Jetbrains Hub. I have created an app within the Azure App registrations portal.

Under the heading "Authorization Service Endpoints" I changed the Authorization and Token endpoints to the ones found within the Azure App registration. Specifically the OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (v2) and OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v2) URL.

I am using the following scopes: `email offline_access openid profile User.Read`

Everything seemed to work fine, I click on the auth module login button and get redirected to my organisation's portal and am asked to login. Once I login however I am redirected back to my Hub environment and the only error I receive is: "Cannot retrieve details from the user profile in the OAuth provider." I have tested this with multiple accounts.

Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following these steps in the documentation should do the trick: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/hub/azure-ad-auth-module.html#common-tenant-setup I've just set it up in my local environment and it works fine. So please check that you've not missed anything and followed the steps. Thanks.

If you've done everything per doc, but the issue still persists, the best solution would be sharing the details with the [Jetbrains Hub support](https://hub-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) directly.

Comment: When logging into Hub via the Azure auth module it creates a separate account. Deleting this account and changing my own login ID to that what the Azure auth module created doesn't let me login via the Azure auth module. Does the Azure auth module work for you with existing accounts?

Comment: The emails should match if you expect to log in to an existing account. It will add Azure credentials to the account in question. Then when logging in, Hub will match your Azure credentials with the Hub ones.